# Missing ; before statement: Google Scripts

Tags: java

I have not been able to fix this error: Missing ; before statement. (line 2, file "Code").   I have searched for an answer on this site as well as other places and have found 1 or 2 related answers.  Unfortunately they prove useless because they are specific to a certain condition.  Here is the first ten lines of my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class quizzed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int restart = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to a capital quiz!  Ready. Go!");
```

Thank you.

Comment: You appear to be trying to include *Java* (rather than Javascript) into the function. Are you sure that's supported? Where are you expecting Swing to run? Can you give a reference to any documentation doing anything like this?

Comment: Please remove the google-apps-script tag from this question.

Answer (score 0):

If this is `Java` you shouldn't have the first line `function myFunction() {`

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class quizzed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int restart = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to a capital quiz!  Ready. Go!");
    }
    //your function goes here
    void myFunction() {
        //more code
    }
}
```

For more information on import layout see here:
http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Package%20and%20Import%20Statements

Comment: I have deleted the function myFunction(){ but it does not not seem do do anything.  I have two things that might help.  This is Java and I first wrote this in Eclipse.